# Why would trivial copy/move contructibility depend on trivial destructibility?

Tags: c++, c++11, trivially-copyable

A class with all special functions defaulted except a non-trivial destructor is not trivially move or copy constructible. See https://godbolt.org/z/o83rPz for an example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Sample
{
public:
        Sample(Sample const&) = default;
        Sample(Sample&&) = default;
        Sample& operator=(Sample const&) = default;
        Sample& operator=(Sample&&) = default;
        ~Sample() {}
};

static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Sample>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<Sample>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<Sample>::value, ""); // Fails with GCC and Clang
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_constructible<Sample>::value, ""); // Fails with GCC and Clang
static_assert(std::is_copy_assignable<Sample>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable<Sample>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable<Sample>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_assignable<Sample>::value, "");
```

Both GCC and Clang fail the corresponding assertions, while ICC passes. Strange enough, assignments are not affected, despite I could understand that the assigned-to object needs to be destroyed. But it seems to be right the other way around. Why? And why does ICC disagree?

Comment: See the notes section here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible

Comment: @Nathan Could be an answer in there?

Comment: The relevant LWG is [2827](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2827).

Answer (score 0):

I see that comments already mention it. The answer is present in the notes section here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible:

> Same applies to `is_trivially_copy_constructible`, which, in these implementations, also requires that the destructor is trivial: [GCC bug 51452](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51452) [LWG issue 2116](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2116).